# InStream video ads and the YouTube iframe API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How is it determined if an InStream (video) ad is to be presented when using the YouTube iframe API? On my site, through limited observation, I seemed to not get any until I began using AdWords and Analytics. I also seem to not get ads when using Incognito mode in Chrome.

My site lets users create music video playlists. InVideo (overlay) ads are fine as they do not interrupt the music. However, frequent InStream ads are extremely annoying and almost defeat the purpose of the site.

Furthermore, is there any way, while adhering to the TOS, to prevent InStream ads? I see a lot of noncompliant sites have implemented their own video players, but see no compliant way to compete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of preventing advertising (or forms of advertising) while adhering to the TOS unless you are the content owner for the videos being played.

I don't believe the method for determining what kind of ad to display is a youtube API (or programming) related question, so is probably OT here.